# How do I re-enable autocomplete on VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, autofill

[image: VSCode Screenshot]

Whenever I am in my editor I can no longer press the enter key to select the autofill suggestion. Instead, VSCode highlights the filepath as I am typing then returns to a new line when I attempt to select the suggestion with the enter key. Tab doesn't work either, as it merely deselects the filepath forcing me to click on it again to resume typing.

This problem began recently, and I have toggled everything I could find in the settings to no avail. It's driving me crazy!

Comment: what's the value of your `editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter` setting?

Comment: It's toggled to on

Comment: Are you in the middle of an incomplete [snippet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) when this happens? If so, do things work as expected when you're not in the middle of an incomplete snippet?

Comment: Nope, the problem only occurs when I am attempting to add a value to a property in an HTML element. The issue isn't present during CSS or JS for example.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue on my VS Code 1.75.1 Ubuntu Snap installation. You might need to provide more details about how to reproduce this and experiment with different settings and on different machines.

Comment: Ok, thanks for trying. It's definitely an issue with a setting I must have inadvertently changed or with the VSCode update I recently installed on my virtual machine. My buddy isn't having this issue and she hasn't updated her's yet, so now I'm wondering if that's related.